# Guice: Fallback to default implementation on a particular condition

Tags: guice

I am new to guice.

I have a file(a json file) in which i defined some data. This is optional. I have to read the data from the file(using FileBasedImpl), if the file exists. Otherwise, i should fetch the data from "DefaultImpl" class, where i return a hard-coded data.

How to achieve this from guice bindings?

```
interface SomeService {
  Map<String, String> getData();
}

class FileBasedImpl implements SomeService {
   /* Reads from a file */
   Map<String, String> getData() {
      //Check if file is present, then read the data
   }
}

class DefaultImpl implements SomeService {
  /* Returns hard-coded data */
  Map<String, String> getData() {
    return new HashMap()<>..;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a provider (either by implementing the interface or adding a provides method to your module) that tries to read the content and provide one or the other bean depending on the result:

```
...
@Provides
public SomeService someService() {
    File file = ....;
    return (file.exists) ? new FileBasedImpl(file) : new DefaultImpl();
}
...
```

Be careful, though, conditional logic in modules is a [documented anti-pattern](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AvoidConditionalLogicInModules). But in cases like this, It is a good and working solution, that from time to time has to be done ...